# Under what conditions does $f(g(x))$ continuous and $g(x)$ continuous imply $f(x)$ is continuous

Tags: continuity, function-and-relation-composition

Take that $g(x)$ is continuous and surjective, and that the codomain of $f(x)$ is a metric space. Is this enough?

One knows that $(f(g(W)))^{-1}=g^{-1}(f^{-1}(W))$ is open if $W$ is open in the codomain. We also know that $g^{-1}(V)$ is open for $V$ an open set. However, $g^{-1}(Z)$ can still be open if $Z=f^{-1}(W)$ is not open, right? Are there additional conditions on $g$ that could be put in place to allow for the result? Do we already have enough?

ASSUME $g$ is not constant.

Comment: I think $g$ needs to be a homeomorphism, but it depends on the codomain. For example, if the codomain of $f$ is just a point, then it doesn't matter what $g$ is. If you're quantifying over all codomains, I'm pretty sure $g$ has to be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Can you explain why the condition of homeomorphism on $g$ would prove the result?

Comment: For a homeomorphism $g^{-1}(U)$ is open if and only if $U$ is open, so $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(V))$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open.